# need to take the file from user dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a code where I want the user to provide the location of the file and it will run the checks which I have coded.
Here I have hardcoded the excel path but I want it dynamic.

I was trying Tkinter to code and dynamically read but I am getting an error:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import pandas as pd
import csv
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')


def open_file():
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Python Files', 
    '*.csv')])
      if file is not None:
         content = file.read()
            print(content)

btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file())
btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10)
prac = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Python Files', 
'*.csv')])
 content = prac.read()

content["latlong"] ='FALSE'
content.loc[(content["LONGITUDE"] >= 70.0000) & 
(content["LONGITUDE"] <= 
98.0000) & (content["LONGITUDE"] != 'nan') & 
 (content["LATITUDE"] != 
'nan'), ["latlong"]] = 'TRUE'
 file.to_csv("C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
 work/practice1.csv")
 writer = content[content["latlong"]=='TRUE']
 writer.to_csv('C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
 work/newfile1.csv', 
 index=False)
 writer = content[content["latlong"]=='TRUE']
 writer.to_csv('C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python
 work/outputfiles/latlong1.csv', index=False)
 mainloop()
```

#but this code is giving me an error:content["latlong"] ='FALSE'
   #TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment.
 This code is working fine for me but I have harcoded the path:

```
def latlong_func():
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
work/Gap1`.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['SUPPLIER_ID','ACTION'])
data["latlong"] ='FALSE'
data.loc[(data["LONGITUDE"] >= 70.0000) & (data["LONGITUDE"] 
<= 98.0000)&
(data["LONGITUDE"] != 'nan') & (data["LATITUDE"] != 'nan'), 
["latlong"]] 
= 'TRUE'
data.to_csv("C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
work/practice1.csv")
writer = data[data["latlong"]=='TRUE']
writer.to_csv('C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
work/newfile1.csv', 
index=False)
writer = data[data["latlong"]=='TRUE']
writer.to_csv('C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
work/outputfiles/latlong1.csv', index=False)
```

what needs to be corrected if I am using tkinter. and what piece of code i 
   should apply if not using tkinter

Comment: Have a look at argparse which will help you on How to pass arg from command line.
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: you shoudl use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile` to get filename instead of opened file object. And then you can use filename with `pd.read_csv` . Using `content = prac.read()` you read it as plain text so you get all in one string in `content` so you can't use it like DataFrame and you can't do `content[...]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `askopenfilename` to get filename instead opened file object. Filename you can use with `pd.read_csv(filename)` instead of using `prac.read()`

So first I made function

```
def latlong_func(filename):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # rest
```

so it get filename and use it with pandas.

And later I made function

```
def get_filename():

    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('Python Files', '*.csv')])

    if filename:
        lbl['text'] = filename
        latlong_func(filename)
    else:
        lbl['text'] = 'not selected'
```

to get filename and execute `latlong_func(filename)`. It also display filename in `Label` in window.

This function is assigned to button

```
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=get_filename)
```

---

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


def latlong_func(filename):
    # filename instead of r'C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python work/Gap1.csv'
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)

    #df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['SUPPLIER_ID','ACTION'])

    data["latlong"] = 'FALSE'
    data.loc[
        (data["LONGITUDE"] >= 70.0000) & (data["LONGITUDE"] <= 98.0000) &
        (data["LONGITUDE"] != 'nan') & (data["LATITUDE"] != 'nan'),
        ["latlong"]
    ] = 'TRUE'

    data.to_csv("C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python work/practice1.csv")

    writer = data[data["latlong"]=='TRUE']
    writer.to_csv('C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python work/newfile1.csv', index=False)
    writer.to_csv('C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python work/outputfiles/latlong1.csv', index=False)


def get_filename():

    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('Python Files', '*.csv')])

    if filename:
        lbl['text'] = filename # display filename in Label
        latlong_func(filename)
    else:
        lbl['text'] = 'not selected'


# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')

lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename')
lbl.pack(side='top', pady=10)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=get_filename)
btn.pack(side='top', pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me..can you also tell if i want to read two  csv files

Comment: in  `get_filename` use `askopenfilename()` two times or use `askopenfilenames()` - with `s` at the end - which let you select many files in dialog window and it gives list with all selected filenames or empty list.

Comment: I am getting an error while solving changing it to askopen filenames. My data is in two different files and now when i want to compare those file how can i do that.could you please help

Comment: you can use `filename1 = askopenfilename(..)` and `filename2 = askopenfilename(..)` and you will have files in two variables and you will know which is first. Or you can use `filenames = askopenfilenames(..)` with **s** at the end and then you have list with files and you have to use `filenames[0]`, `filenames[1]`. I don't know if with `askopenfilenames` you can control which file will be first on list - first which you click in dialog window or it will sort them alphabetically.

Comment: can u plss help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162499/need-to-compare-two-csv-files-in-pyhton