# need to compare two csv files in python

Tags: python, excel

I have two files in csv format and wants to compare the columns.i want the list to be present in other csv file

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
def latlong_func(filename):
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
data["latlong"] = 'FALSE'
data.loc[(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9500)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9501)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9502)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9503)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9504)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9506)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9507)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9508)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9509)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9510)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9511)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9514)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9515)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9516)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9517)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9520)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9521)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9522)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9527)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9529)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9529)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9531)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9536)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9529)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9529)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9529)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9540)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9542)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9544)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9545)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9546)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9547)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9548)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9549)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9550)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9551)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9552)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9553)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9554)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9555)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9556)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9557)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9558)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9559)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"]==9561)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"]==9562)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9563)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9564)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9566)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9513)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9569)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9572)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9574)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9575)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9576)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9577)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9578)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9580)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9581)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9584)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9585)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9586)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9990)|
(data["FAC_TYPE"] ==9589), ["latlong"]] ='TRUE'

data.to_csv("C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
work/practice1.csv")

writer = data[data["latlong"]=='TRUE']
writer.to_csv('C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
work/newfile1.csv', index=False)
writer.to_csv('C:/Users/patesari/Desktop/python 
work/outputfiles/latlong1.csv', index=False)
def get_filename():

filename0 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('Python Files', '*.csv')])
filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('Python Files', '*.csv')])
if filename:
    lbl['text'] = filename
    latlong_func(filename)
else:
    lbl['text'] = 'not selected'
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename')
lbl.pack(side='top', pady=10)
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=get_filename)
btn.pack(side='top', pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

In above i take file dynamically but I have hard coded the "or" ones.I want to compare it with 2nd csv  file where the list is present.not the hard coded one. 
how can we store the list in csv in particular path and then compare that file

Comment: now you have `filename0` and `filename1` but you still use old variable `filename` - it is mistake

Comment: if you have two filenames then you need two labels to display names, and use you have to use `read_csv` two times to read both files, and keep data in two variables, etc.

Comment: your code has wrong indentions and we don't know which lines are in functions

Comment: can you help me with the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you try to do with data so I keep empty `work_with_data(data1, data2)` but this code shows how to get two filenames, use `read_csv()` two times and finally run function `work_with_data(data1, data2)`

It also use two `Labels` to display two filenames.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# --- functions ---

def work_with_data(data1, data2):

    print(data1.head())
    print(data2.head())

    # ... here you can works with data1, data2 ...


def get_filenames():
    # default values before reading data

    data1 = None
    data2 = None

    # first filename and data1

    filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('CSV files', '*.csv')])

    if filename1:
        lbl1['text'] = filename1
        data1 = pd.read_csv(filename1)
    else:
        lbl1['text'] = 'Filename 1 not selected'

    # second filename and data2

    filename2 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('CSV files', '*.csv')])

    if filename2:
        lbl2['text'] = filename2
        data2 = pd.read_csv(filename2)
    else:
        lbl2['text'] = 'Filename 2 not selected'

    # start working with data

    if data1 is not None and data2 is not None:
       work_with_data(data1, data2)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry('200x200')

lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename 1')
lbl1.pack(side='top', pady=10)

lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename 2')
lbl2.pack(side='top', pady=10)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=get_filenames)
btn.pack(side='top', pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** I changed little code so you can use `pandas` or `csv.reader` in `work_with_data`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def work_with_data(filename1, filename2):

    # --- use pandas ---

    data1 = pd.read_csv(filename1)
    data2 = pd.read_csv(filename2)

    # ... here you can works with data1, data2 ...

    # --- or csv.reader ---

    fp1 = open(filename1)
    reader1 = csv.reader(fp1)

    fp2 = open(filename2)
    reader2 = csv.reader(fp2)

    # ... here you can works with reader1, reader2 ...

    fp2.close()   
    fp1.close()   


def get_filenames():
    # default values before reading data

    filename1 = None
    filename2 = None

    # first filename

    filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('CSV files', '*.csv')])

    if filename1:
        lbl1['text'] = filename1
    else:
        lbl1['text'] = 'Filename 1 not selected'

    # second filename

    filename2 = askopenfilename(filetypes =[('CSV files', '*.csv')])

    if filename2:
        lbl2['text'] = filename2
    else:
        lbl2['text'] = 'Filename 2 not selected'

    # start working with data

    if filename1 and filename2:
        work_with_data(filename1, filename1)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry('200x200')

lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename 1')
lbl1.pack(side='top', pady=10)

lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text='Select filename 2')
lbl2.pack(side='top', pady=10)

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=get_filenames)
btn.pack(side='top', pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In data 1 i want a column from 1st csv file; and in data 2 another column. now if the data of 2nd csv present  in 1st csv(value of columns) then it should report such values in another csv

Comment: you have all columns from 1st csv in data1, and all columns from 2nd file in data2. Now you have to use data1 and data2 to create data3 with expected columns and laver save it in 3rd csv file. But I don't know what you expect in data3. Maybe `data1["FAC_TYPE"].isin( data2["FAC_TYPE"] )` ? Doc: [pandas.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: yes, i need data1["FAC_TYPE"].isin( data2["FAC_TYPE"] )

Comment: import csv

data = {}  # creating list to store the data

with open('check.csv', 'r') as lookuplist, open('LOT55.csv', 'r') as csvinput, open('Output5.csv', 'w') as f_output:
 reader1 = csv.reader(lookuplist)
 reader2 = csv.reader(csvinput)
 csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
 _tempFqdn = []
 for i,dt in enumerate(reader1):
     if i==0:
         continue
     _tempFqdn.append(dt[0].strip())
 for i,col in enumerate(reader2):
     if i==0:
         continue
     if col[9].strip() in _tempFqdn:
         csv_output.writerow(col)

Comment: I have tried the above code can u help me know how can i take them dynamically from user.both the files

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page - you will have more space for code and it will be more readable. I you have space to better describe what do you try to do.

Comment: can't you use code from this question to do it ? You already have two `askopenfilename` in example.

Comment: I changed example so now `work_with_data` gets filenames and you can use `csv.reader` instead of `pandas`